# How to play Multiplayer in Age of Empires II?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

How to play Multiplayer game in Age of Empires II: Age of King? With an application or from the game?

Comment: local, or across the internet?  We played tons of AoE2 in the 1990s on a LAN ... can't remember if it was IP or IPX, though.

Comment: [You can play AOE 2 through Voobly.](http://www.voobly.com/games/view/13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access multiplayer on the main menu.

[image]

EDIT: Just read that they shut down servers in 2006. You could try services like GameRanger or get the HD version on Steam (multiplayer via steam)

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Empires_II:_The_Age_of_Kings) (see "Multiplayer")

Comment: When i'm clicked Multiplayer Button (then clicking Show Games), i not see any rooms. My version is 2.0A.